# How to Sync call in Node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, iife

I have following code snippet:

```
var  array = [1, 2, 3];
var data = 0;
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
  asyncFunction(data++);
}
console.log(data);
executeOtherFunction(data);
```

I am expecting value of data as 3 but I see it as 0 due to `asyncFunction`. How do I call `executeOtherFunction` when all the `asyncFunction` calls are done?

Comment: Is this your actual code, or an attempt to simplify it?  As it is, the value of `data` is 3 at the `console.log` line, which is exactly what you'd expect.

Comment: Edited. Yes this is not exact code. I have given a simplified logic but this is exact flow of it.

Comment: Okay, but my point was that the code you posted does exactly what one would expect.  You should unsimplify it until it exhibits the problematic behavior.

Comment: My asyc function gets called multiple times in a loop and I need to utilize some data updated by async function. And when async function is executed for last time. I need to call different method utilizing all data generated by all async calls

Answer (score 2):

Use [`async.each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback):

```
var async = require('async');

var data  = 0;
var array = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

async.each(array, function(item, done) {
  asyncFunction(data++, done);
}, function(err) {
  if (err) ... // handle error
  console.log(data);
  executeOtherFunction(data);
});
```

(assuming that `asyncFunction` takes two arguments, a number (`data`) and a callback)

Comment: i recommend using the alias `async.forEach` which is identical to `async.each` but it's more obvious that it's an asynchronous version of `forEach`

Comment: @Plato I didn't even know it existed! Will start using it from now on, surely makes more sense :)

Answer (score 2):

If `asyncFunction` is implemented like the following:

```
function asyncFunction(n) {
    process.nextTick(function() { /* do some operations */ });
}
```

Then you'll have no way of knowing when `asyncFunction` is actually done executing because it's left the callstack. So it'll need to notify when execution is complete.

```
function asyncFunction(n, callback) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        /* do some operations */
        callback();
    });
}
```

This is using the simple callback mechanism. If you want to use one of freakishly many modules to have this handled for you, go ahead. But implementing something like with basic callbacks might not be pretty, but isn't difficult.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
var data = 0;
var cntr = 0;

function countnExecute() {
    if (++cntr === array.length)
        executeOtherFunction(data);
}

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    asyncFunction(data++, countnExecute);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this module, I think this is what you're looking for:

https://github.com/caolan/async