# Synchronous call to Redis Server

Tags: node.js, redis, asynchronous

With the following code, I access the Redis client asynchronously, with a casual Node JS way to code:

```
function start()
{
    var redis = require("redis");
    var host = "127.0.0.1";
    var port = 6379;
    var client = redis.createClient(port, host);    
    
    client.on("error", function (err) {
        console.log("Error " + err);
    });

    client.set("hi", "hey", redis.print);

    return client;
}

function getValue(client, callback)
{
    client.get("hi", function (err, res) {
        callback(res);
    });

}

var c = start();
getValue(c, function(r){
    console.log('Result ' + r);
});
```

And the console prints 'Result hey'.

Instead of using a callback in the getValue() function, I would like to make a classical return:

```
function getValue(client)
{
    client.get("hi", function (err, res) {
        return res;
    });

}
```

in order to have:

```
var r = getValue(c);
console.log(r);
```

So to make a synchronous call to the Redis server. I've tried async, fibrous, ... library but I'm stuck and cannot find out how to do that.

Comment: You can't directly return an asynchronous result from a function as the function has already returned by the time the result is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to pass in a callback to your client.set() call.

```
client.set("hi", "hey", function (err, res) {
  cb(err, res);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar thread can be found at :
[How to Sync call in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273700/how-to-sync-call-in-node-js)

You can consider using [step](https://github.com/creationix/step) or [node-finish](https://github.com/chaoran/node-finish) to achieve what you want